# Javascript show/hide toggle -- possible before page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, session

To show/hide an item, I am usually doing an ajax call to get the session variable. This way, I have the variable set server-side, and when I render the page I can show or hide a section accordingly.

However, I was wondering if it would be possible to do this in javascript, without loading the page **and afterwards** toggling the visibility of an item. For example:

```
<div class="section">...</div>

if (localStorage.getItem('toggle') == 'hide') {
    $('.section').hide();
}
```

This loads the section, and then hides it after the page loads, creating a 'show-then-hide' user experience (as if it's a momentary mistake). Is there a way to prevent this (excluding hiding it to begin with, and then showing it after, if needed)?

Comment: What about doing it the opposite...hide with css... if `getItem('toggle') =='hide'` then do nothing, otherwise use something like `slideDown()` to show

Comment: ... or you could just add a `hide` class, `.hide{display:none}`, to the element on the server side?

Comment: I think if you put the `<script>` that hides it directly after the element, it will run while the page is loading. Don't put the code in `$(document).ready()`, since that waits until after the page is loaded.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use a `class` or an inline `style` to hide the element initially.